# No route matches {:action=>"change_name", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've added gem "devise" and I got this error. I can't understand what's wrong with my code. Thanks in advance!

**Error:**

```
def user_form
    common_options = { validate: true, html: { class: 'user-form' } }
    form_options = current_user ? [ current_user, { url: change_user_name_path(current_user.id), method: :post, validate: true }.merge(common_options) ] : [ User.new, { validate: true }.merge(common_options) ]
    form_for *form_options do |f|
      yield f
    end
  end
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  devise_for :usernames
  root 'surveys#index'
  resources 'surveys'
  resources 'attempts'
  resources 'users', only: [:create]

  delete 'attempts/:survey_id/:user_id' => 'attempts#delete_user_attempts', as: :delete_user_attempts

  post 'user/:id/change_name' => 'users#change_name', as: :change_user_name
```

**Controller:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    session[:user_id] = User.create(user_params).id
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def change_name
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update(user_params)
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

Can someone help with this problem?

Comment: when did you get this error? What url did you call? You might have called change_name action without passing the id

Comment: @Sajin `form_options = current_user ? [ current_user, { url: change_user_name_path(current_user.id), method: :post, validate: true }.merge(common_options) ]`

Comment: You need to pass `current_user` instead of `current_user.id`.  Do you have data in current user ?

Comment: @Vishal, passing `current_user` shows the same error

Comment: Also I forgot to mention this method: `def current_user`
    @user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  `end`

Comment: @ElzhanZeinulla If You are using devise than you dont need to create any method for getting current_user. it is default method of devise. remove that method from you model .

Comment: @Vishal, thanks a lot, that solved the issue. Such a silly mistake

Comment: @ElzhanZeinulla If this is helpful to you . Can i post answer and will upvote and accept the answer ? it will help me a lot. :) It will also help other users

Comment: @Vishal, of course

Comment: @ElzhanZeinulla I added answer . please upvote and accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove method `current_user` from your model. Because `current_user` is default method of devise which return current logged in user. You are overriding method of devise. that's why you getting error of `nil ID` because your current_user don't has any value.

It will solve your problem .